# How to Implement Dispose In Inheriting Class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dispose

I am using `SmtpClient` in the .NET-3.5 framework (meaning it does not implement `IDisposable`), but would like to put it in a using statement like so:

```
using (var client = new DisposableSmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 25)
{ Credentials = new NetworkCredential(), EnableSsl = false })
{
    client.Send(EmailAddress,
                EmailAddress,
                Subject,
                body);
}
```

So I created the following:

```
class DisposableSmtpClient : SmtpClient, IDisposable
{
    bool disposed; 

    public DisposableSmtpClient(string mailServer, int port) : base(mailServer, port)
    {
        // var client = new SmtpClient(mailServer, port);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Which works fine for sending the message, but when debugging, it throws a `StackOverflow` exception (as `this.Dispsoe();` will just call itself forever).

I tried calling `this.Dispose(true)` as per many other SO questions, but this complains that `No overload for method 'Dispose' takes 1 arguments`.

`base.Dispoe()` also does work, because of course `'SmtpClient' does not conatin a definition for 'Dispose'`

Finally, I also tried the signature `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)`, but I get `Dispose(): no suitable method found to override`

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You are not actually disposing (or clearing up) anything, so why bother?

Comment: @Maarten I guess I assumed that there are some resources which still exist after calling `Send`, because the later implementations of `SmtpClient` implement `IDisposable` - is this not the case?

Comment: Maybe but adding an empty Dispose-method will not do anything. You need to actually do something to clean anything up.

Comment: I  guess its better to  use standalone component for email when you are using .Net 3.5. Something like https://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-dotnet.asp. In order to implement Dispose properly you need to  free some internal smtpclient resources but you dont have access to them. So  if you just implement it like empty Dispose method it will  definately not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - you don't need to dispose anything, so you don't need `Dispose`.

Just go for new:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com", 25)
{ Credentials = new NetworkCredential(), EnableSsl = false };

client.Send(EmailAddress,
            EmailAddress,
            Subject,
            body);
```

2 - If you *really* want to use `using` (and I don't know why you should), you have to implement an empty dispose (because you don't have anything to dispose to begin with):

```
class DisposableSmtpClient : SmtpClient, IDisposable
{
    public DisposableSmtpClient(string mailServer, int port) : base(mailServer, port)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // anything to do, so don't do anything.
    }
}
```

IMO, KISS is a principle you should really consider.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Do you know what `SmtpClient.Dispose()` actually does in later versions of the framework?

Comment: Well, in later versions it disposes the resources used by the new SmtpClient implementation. The thing is, you WILL need to review this code when targeting .Net 4. Or, you can use conditional compilation in the Dispose implementation in solution 2. E.g. wrap the implementation in a #if Net40 conditional. But it's not simple and if you don't need simultaneous targeting of different framework versions, I wouldn't bother.